# string.format a string in AngularJS dynamically

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a translate directive that takes a key and provides the text in the current locale which could be any language.

So for example you can do either:

```
<p translate="yes">#App.MyString</p>
```

or

```
<p>{{'#App.MyString' | translate }}</p>
```

And it will print in the language of the selected culture.

```
<p> This is my string </p>
```

The filter in place to handle translations is:

```
export class TranslateFilter {
        public static build(getTextCatalog: Infrastructure.IGettextCatalog) {
            var filter = (resourceKey, resourceType, resourcePrefix) => {
                if (resourcePrefix != null) {
                    resourceKey = `${resourcePrefix}.${resourceKey}`;
                }
                return getTextCatalog.getString(`#${resourceType}.${resourceKey}`);
            };
            return filter;
        }
    }
```

I want to now also try to combine this with string.Format.

So if the `#App.KeyString` contains a string like this: `'Hi {0}. Welcome to {1}'` I can do a string.Format using dynamic values.

I can do that within the controller but I was wondering if there's a way it could be done on the html file.

For example something like this:

```
<p translate="yes" format="{{scope.name}},{{scope.place}}">#App.MyString</p>
```

or

```
<p>{{'#App.MyString' | translate | format:[$scope.name, $scope.place] }}</p>
```

would print

```
'Hi Nick! Welcome to Narnia'
```

Any ideas?